# Answering question does not bump it?

Tags: bug

I posted an answer to

[Grothendieck spaces and total subspaces of the dual](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155154/grothendieck-spaces-and-total-subspaces-of-the-dual)

and it bumped the question to the top under the tagged lists but not on the front page even though I have that page set to active.  I found the question on page six and noticed that

[classifying $\infty$-toposes for topological/localic groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155166/classifying-infty-toposes-for-topological-localic-groups)

was just above the first question and had been answered a few minutes before.

What gives?

Comment: It shows up on the active front page for me.  Were you perhaps looking at the newest questions front page?

Comment: Sometimes the front view lists questions not in chronological order of recent activity, perhaps because the order is cached.  It does reflect time stamps, e.g. sometimes 1m then 23s then 5m appears for the top 3 questions.

Comment: Sorry for the many back and forth  (it seems I am a bit confused today). It is starnge at the moment things seem to behave differently than before. Or, I misobserved them before, so I deleted my answer. That it takes more than 15 minutes (as you said on a comment to my delete answer), and from the timestamps it seems at least almost 25, is certainly unusually long.

Comment: How do you order the questions? Do you view them through the front page or through the Questions page? If the latter, perhaps it wasn't set to "active" but perhaps "newest"?

Comment: Always through the questions page with active set, Asaf.

Comment: Finding out about this, I know we tweaked how things bump, but I can't quite remember the particulars.